# how to delete a test file after finished testing in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I create a test where in setUp I create file like so :

```
 class TestSomething :
     def setUp(self):
         # create file
         fo = open('some_file_to_test','w')
         fo.write('write_something')
         fo.close()

     def test_something(self):
         # call some function to manipulate file
         ...
         # do some assert
         ...

     def test_another_test(self):
         # another testing with the same setUp file
         ...
```

at the end of testing, regardless either succeed or not, I want the testing file gone,so
**how to delete the file after i have finished testing?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're using a *unittest*-esque framework (i.e. *nose*, etc.), you would want to use the `tearDown` method to delete the file, as that will run after each test.

```
def tearDown(self):
    os.remove('some_file_to_test')
```

If you want to only delete this file after all the tests, you could create it in the method `setUpClass` and delete it in the method `tearDownClass`, which will run before and after **all** tests have run, respectively.

Comment: I think you mean to create the file in `setupClass()` and delete it in `tearDownClass()`. There is also an analagous `setupModule()` and `tearDownModule()`.

Comment: @mhawke thank you for pointing to the right direction, tearDownClass() is what i was looking for

Answer (score 11):

Other option is to add a function to be called after tearDown() using [`addCleanup()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup) method of TestCase:

```
class TestSomething(TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
         # create file
         fo = open('some_file_to_test','w')
         fo.write('write_something')
         fo.close()
         # register remove function
         self.addCleanup(os.remove, 'some_file_to_test')
```

It is more convenient than `tearDown()` in cases where there are a lot of files or when they are created with random names because you can add a cleanup method just after file creation.

Answer (score 5):

Write a tearDown method:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown

```
def tearDown(self):
    import os
    os.remove('some_file_to_test')
```

Also have a look at the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module and see if it's useful in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using `pytest` or other class-less testing frameworks, use self deleting temp files instead:

```
import tempfile
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
     f.write('write_something')
     # assert stuff here

# Here the file is closed and thus deleted
```